# How can I make a UINavigationController's UINavigationBar invisible or at least change color

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uikit, uinavigationbar

I have a UINavigationController that is Linked to a ViewController that is set as RootController. I have enabled the UINavigationBar and put 3 UIViews each with a UIButton inside. Ideally I would like to make the UINavigationBar completely invisible, but I would also settle for setting the color to the background color of my ViewController. I am working in swift and I have tried things like

```
self.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
self.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
self.navigationBar.translucent = true
```

However nothing changes. Is there a correct way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

In swift, you can do:

```
self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
```

Please refer to [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/setNavigationBarHidden:animated:) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I am also using Swift and was calling `setNavigationBarHidden` with no effect. I created a helper method in Obj-C that calls `setNavigationBarHidden:animated:` on a given navigation controller, and that works fine. So apparently this is just a bug, very frustrating.