# swift xcode hide navigation bar for specific view

Tags: ios, swift

I want to hide the navigation bar for a specific view, and add my own custom "back button"

The way I am doing this now is by:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true
    }
```

It works but it takes 0.2 sec before the bar gets hidden, so you kinda can see it jump up once the view loads. Is there any other way to hide it?

Comment: Do it in the viewDidLoad for that view because the viewDidAppear runs once the view is shown to the user

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make a UINavigationController's UINavigationBar invisible or at least change color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24519790/how-can-i-make-a-uinavigationcontrollers-uinavigationbar-invisible-or-at-least)

Answer (score 4):

I was facing the same issue, this was fixed using the following method:

```
self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 1):

Do it in the viewDidLoad for that view because the viewDidAppear runs once the view is shown to the user. You could also try setting the alpha of the navbar to 0 for faster action.

Comment: should I type "self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true" or "navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true" without "self." both works ?

Comment: @KiwoTew Without self i'd prefer. Both are the same cause you're writing the code within the class anyway!!!

Answer (score 0):

For Swift 3:
As Arayman Goes noted, add this to viewDidLoad:

```
self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
```

Answer (score 0):

just write this code in that swift file you want to hide the nav bar ... (Swift - 3)

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: animated)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: animated)
}
```